# error C2248: 'X::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'X'

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

Similar questions are already asked on stackoverflow. I do have looked at them but still unable to resolve the issue I am facing

I have a structure **X** with few member variables including a **mutex**. I am using this mutex to lock access to member vector called **vecIds** when pushing elements in it from multiple threads.

Further, as I donot want objects of type **X** to be copyable or copy constructable, I declare copy constructor and copy assignment operator functions as private

```
struct X
{
    bool a;
    unsigned value;
    std::vector<unsigned> vecIds;
    std::mutex mutex;

    X(): a(false), value(0), mutex(){}

 private:
    X( X const &x);
    X& operator=( Xconst &x);
 };
```

Somewhere in my code I am creating vector of 100 objects of type X. When I compile my code I see the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xutility(2466): error C2248: 'X::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'X'
X.h(12): see declaration of 'X::operator ='    
X.h(2): see declaration of 'X'
```

I donot seem to figure out where is the problem

Comment: Some vector operations require the element type to be copyable (e.g. initializing a vector to a non-zero size using a non-default constructor); and some require copy-or-move, e.g. `push_back`.  Post the actual code that triggers the error to get better help.

Comment: @molbdnilo with `emplace_back` , or by definiing a move-constructor and moving it in

Comment: @molbdnilo: I use following vector constructor to create my 100 objects "vector( size_type count );". Following is the description for this vector constructor on cppreference: "Constructs the container with count value-initialized (default constructed, for classes) instances of T. No copies are made."

Comment: Almost all modifying vector operations requires the element to be at least `MoveAssignable` and/or `MoveInsertable`.

Comment: BTW, in C++11, the way to forbid method is `= delete`.

Comment: I have tried delete. I am using VS2012. It doesn't work

Comment: @T.C.: No where in my code I am copying objects of type X. Once all 100 objects are constructed, I am just writing to individual objects here and there.

Comment: @nurabha post the actual code that causes the error instead of describing it

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that triggers the error, and the error it causes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a VS2012 bug fixed in VS2013. VS2012's implementation of

```
explicit vector(size_type n);
```

calls `resize()`, which requires the element to be both `DefaultInsertable` and `MoveInsertable`. This is nonconforming, since the constructor itself only requires `DefaultInsertable`<sup>*</sup>. (To make it worse, its `resize()` implementation calls `erase()`, which requires the type to be `MoveAssignable`...)

It's mentioned in [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/02/10430213.aspx) (search for "`vector<DefaultConstructible>(10)`").

If you are using a fixed-length container, consider using a `std::array<X, 100>`.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>When the default allocator is used, the `*Insertable` requirements basically translate to `*Constructible`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can you share the MSDN page where this bug is discussed ? Thanks

Comment: @nurabha Added a link.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles fine in VS2013, to resolve your problem in a quick way, try a vector of smart pointers

```
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::unique<X>> x(100);
```

Note: your struct X has std::mutex as member, mutex is not copyable nor moveable, which means X is nonCopyable nor moveable.